# saving edited Mathematica image at high resolution

Tags: export, image-processing

I've created several graphs for a book I'm writing by using Mathematica commands to create an output image and then adding labels, etc. with Mathematica's drawing tools.  My issue is that I can't seem to save the edited version of the images at high enough dpi resolution.

I've looked at the Export and ImageResolution commands, but these seem only to work on the original output image not the edited version with my added writing/labels.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: 1) Right click on the image, "Save Graphic As...", then select e.g. the TIFF format, which gives you access to "Options" in the Save dialog. Among the options, you can save an export resolution. 2) Copy the image you want to save, then **paste it as the argument of `Export`**: `Export[fileName, <paste your modified image here>, "ImageFormat", ImageResolution -> etc etc]`.